# Merging and Summing data from SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, union

So I am trying to make a system faster. Currently I am polling the database several thousand times for one transation. I am in the process of making this faster by combining datasets/tables.
Currently I've got 4 tables in my database: Customers, Food Transactions, Drink Transactions and Desert Transactions. (These are placeholder names). These are set up as followed: Each entering customer gets a unique transaction number that will be used to order stuff

```
**Customers Table:**
ID              Customer Name
0               Harvey
1               Jessica
2               Rachel
3               Louis
4               Mike
5               Donna

**Food Table**
Transaction ID  Food ID    Customer ID
1121            4          1
1122            2          0
1125            9          3
1122            7          0
1120            6          2
1122            6          0

**Drinks Table:**
Transaction ID  Drink ID   Customer ID
1121            2          1
1121            4          1
1121            4          1
1120            3          2
1125            1          3
1130            8          4
1132            8          4

**Desert Table:**
Transaction ID  Desert ID  Customer ID
1130            1          4
1125            3          3
1120            3          2
2100            9          5
1118            8          5
1118            7          5
```

Now I have been trying to combine these tables with **FULL OUTER JOIN**, I however think that I might have mis interprated this function. I was able to find the corresponding customer name by using LEFT JOIN.

Does anybody have any clue, how I could create the rest of the following table:

```
**Combined Table**
Transaction IDs     Customer Name       Amount Foods     Amount Drinks     Amount Dessert
2100                Donna               0                0                 1
1132                Mike                0                1                 0
1130                Mike                0                1                 1
1125                Louis               1                1                 1
1122                Harvey              3                0                 0
1121                Jessica             1                3                 0
1120                Rachel              1                1                 1
1118                Donna               0                0                 2
```

A Transaction belongs to one customer, a customer however can have several transaction ID's. Therefore, since the Transaction ID's are unique in the last table I have no idea what you would use as the left table when using a LEFT JOIN statement.

Comment: I updated the question, the final table is different as are the sub tables. The problem lies in the fact that the final table doesn't have an original master table to perform join functions on. So how can I update the query? I posted a new question because I wasn't aware I could alter the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this query?

```
SELECT `Food`.`Customer ID`, `Customers`.`Customer Name`,
   COUNT(DISTINCT `Food`.`Food ID`) as "Amount Foods",
   COUNT(DISTINCT `drink`.`Food ID`) as "Amount drinks",
   COUNT(DISTINCT `desert`.`Food ID`) as "Amount deserts"
FROM `Food` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Customers` ON `food`.`Customer ID` = `Customers`.`ID` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Customers` ON `drink`.`Customer ID` = `Customers`.`ID` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Customers` ON `desert`.`Customer ID` = `Customers`.`ID` 
GROUP BY `Food`.`Customer ID`, `Customers`.`Customer Name`;
```

---

EDIT:

I will suggest to change table structure if this is possible.

- Table 1: Customer (CustomerID, customer_name,...)
- Table 2: Transaction (TransactionID, CustomerID, maybe date, time,...)
- Table 3: Order (OrderID, TransactionID, type (1 - food, 2 - Drink, 3 - desert), date, time,...)

Then you can write query like this

```
SELECT t.transactionid, c.customername,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM order food WHERE  t.transactionid = food.transactionid and food.type = 1) as food_count,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM order drink WHERE  t.transactionid = drink.transactionid and drink.type = 2) as drink_count,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM order desert WHERE  t.transactionid = desert.transactionid and desert.type = 3) as desert_count
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN customer c on t.customerid = c.customerid
GROUP BY t.transactionid, c.customername;
```

Comment: Hi Nebojsa, thanks as well for answering the question. When trying to implement it, it caught my mind that my tables center point are the transaction ids, not necessarily the names. A name can have several transaction ids. But a transaction id can only belong to one person. I changed the question. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: @AlexvanRijs do you have a table with transaction id as primary key?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of writing your query.  It uses correlated subqueries instead of `join`s in the outer query:

```
SELECT c.`Customer ID`, c.`Customer Name`,
       (select COUNT(DISTINCT f.`Food ID`) from Food f where f.`Customer ID` = c.`ID`
       ) as "Amount Foods",
       (select COUNT(DISTINCT d.`Drink ID`) from Drink d where d.`Customer ID` = c.`ID`
       ) as "Amount Drinks",
       (select COUNT(DISTINCT d.`Desert ID`) from Desert d where d.`Customer ID` = c.`ID`
       ) as "Amount Desert",
FROM Customers c ;
```

This does a few things:

- It prevents cartesian products at the outer level, as you add more tables.
- It eliminates the need for a `group by` in the outer query.
- It ensures that all customers are present, even if they have no rows in any of the tables.

Note:  I kept the `count(distinct)`.  However, you probably do not need it.  `count(*)` should be sufficient, unless you know there are duplicate values that you do not want to count.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for you answer. When trying to implement it, it caught my mind that my tables center point are the transaction ids, not necessarily the names. A name can have several transaction ids. But a transaction id can only belong to one person. I changed the question. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: @AlexvanRijs . . . It is actually impolite to change questions after they have answers, when the new questions invalidate answers.